# Auto start/stop Flexible Server using Azure Automation Python RunBook

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-cli, azure-automation

I have been trying to create a script to start my postgresSQL flexible server on weekdays and stop it on Saturday and Sunday for cost optimization.

Referred a link from official Microsoft blog: [enter link description here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/auto-start-stop-flexible-server-using-azure-automation-python/bc-p/3839692#M308)

The test script gives an error:

> error":{"code":"NoRegisteredProviderFound","message":"No registered resource provider found for location 'eastus..
> Note: I have entered the correct subscription ID, Resource Group and Location of server.

Azure CLI command works : az postgres flexible-server start  --resource-group [ResourceGroupName]  --name [ServerName]

Can someone please help me with automation script error? Do we need to establish a connection with PostgresSQL server first? or need to import some extra resource dependencies?

Thank you for your time.

Script:

```
import azure.mgmt.resource
import requests
import automationassets
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD
from datetime import datetime

def get_token(runas_connection, resource_url, authority_url):
    """ Returns credentials to authenticate against Azure resoruce manager """
    from OpenSSL import crypto
    from msrestazure import azure_active_directory
    import adal

    # Get the Azure Automation RunAs service principal certificate
    cert = automationassets.get_automation_certificate("AzureRunAsCertificate")
    pks12_cert = crypto.load_pkcs12(cert)
    pem_pkey = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pks12_cert.get_privatekey())

    # Get run as connection information for the Azure Automation service principal
    application_id = runas_connection["ApplicationId"]
    thumbprint = runas_connection["CertificateThumbprint"]
    tenant_id = runas_connection["TenantId"]

    # Authenticate with service principal certificate
    authority_full_url = (authority_url + '/' + tenant_id)
    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_full_url)
    return context.acquire_token_with_client_certificate(
            resource_url,
            application_id,
            pem_pkey,
            thumbprint)['accessToken']

action = ''
day_of_week = datetime.today().strftime('%A')
if day_of_week == 'Saturday':
    action = 'stop'
elif day_of_week == 'Monday':
    action = 'start'

subscription_id = '<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>'
resource_group = '<RESOURCE_GROUP>'
server_name = '<SERVER_NAME>'

if action: 
    print 'Today is ' + day_of_week + '. Executing ' + action + ' server'
    runas_connection = automationassets.get_automation_connection("AzureRunAsConnection")
    resource_url = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id
    authority_url = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory
    resourceManager_url = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.resource_manager
    auth_token=get_token(runas_connection, resource_url, authority_url)
    url = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/' + subscription_id + '/resourceGroups/' + resource_group + '/providers/Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/' + server_name + '/' + action + '?api-version=2020-02-14-preview'
    response = requests.post(url, json={}, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token})
    print(response.json())
else: 
    print 'Today is ' + day_of_week + '. No action taken'
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    runas_connection =
> automationassets.get_automation_connection("AzureRunAsConnection")
> File "C:\Python27\lib\automationassets.py", line 234, in
> get_automation_connection    connection =
> _client.get_connection_asset(name)  File "C:\Python27\lib\automationassets.py", line 189, in
> get_connection_asset    return self._issue_request(url,
> method=self._GET)  File , in _issue_request   raise
> AutomationAssetNotFound()automationassets.AutomationAssetNotFound.

Message:Asset not found for accountId [Number] controller name [ConnectionsV2Controller] and type [AzureRunAsConnection

Comment: Could you try by testing in a different region to see if that will resolve the issue.

Comment: I am afraid using a different zone is not possible, we are using Azure credits for POC hence only East US zone is available.

Comment: The issue may be specific to the 'eastus.' location.

Comment: Could you please try again and let me know what error you are getting.

Comment: Hi, @Oury-MSFT I have updated the error message in the question thread. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Auto start stop Flexible Server using Azure Automation Python RunBook
Auto start stop Flexible Server using Azure Automation Python RunBook

> Message:Asset not found for accountId [Number] controller name [ConnectionsV2Controller] and type [AzureRunAsConnection]

As per error message the runbook python script is **not able to get the  asset from the connections.**

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/migrate-run-as-accounts-managed-identity?tabs=sa-managed-identity):

> [image]

Microsoft stopped providing RunAs account from 1st April. If you created automation account after that your connections does not contain this **AzureRunAsConnection** connection.

**If you created Account before It the workaround can be you can manually create the AzureRunAsConnection:**

- Go to Automation account >> Shared resources >> Connections >> new Connection and fill all the required details.
  [image]

**If you created Account After 1st april It the workaround**

- You need to change the authentication method in your code to use managed identity
- First you neet tio turn on the managed identity as below
  [image]
- Assign the appropriate role to the managed identity to access the Azure resource.
- Change your runbook code to use a managed identity to authenticate.

For more information you can refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/migrate-run-as-accounts-managed-identity?tabs=sa-managed-identity#migrate-from-an-automation-run-as-account-to-a-managed-identity)